# How can I change the owner of all objects in a Snowflake database clone?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As part of our development lifecycle we clone our prod databases to replace our dev databases, the next step is to apply the correct privileges to the newly cloned databases as our devs need full access to the dev environment whilst they shouldn't have write access to the prod environment.
So I have a requirement to change the owner of all objects in the dev databases to allow the devs to replace and update existing tables, views, procs etc. I have so far been unable to find how to achieve this.

Comment: Hi you can try this statement on the cloned DB and generate the script for granting the ownership. select 'GRANT OWNERSHIP ON TABLE ' || table_name || ' to role new_role copy grants ;' as statmt 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES 
WHERE GRANTOR = 'old_role';

Comment: Thanks, I'd been playing around with this type of thing but hoped there was a slicker way to achieve this than creating a bunch of dynamic scripts. I also found that this method doesn't work for views as they are held in the privileges table as TABLE but grants must be applied to VIEWS, so a little force is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After cloning the database, transfer ownership to another role using the [GRANT OWNERSHIP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-ownership.html) (see also example) function using `COPY CURRENT GRANTS` clause, for example:

```sql
GRANT OWNERSHIP ON DATABASE mydb TO ROLE developer COPY CURRENT GRANTS;    
GRANT OWNERSHIP ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE mydb TO ROLE developer COPY CURRENT GRANTS;
GRANT OWNERSHIP ON ALL TABLES IN DATABASE mydb TO ROLE developer COPY CURRENT GRANTS; 
GRANT OWNERSHIP ON ALL VIEWS IN DATABASE mydb TO ROLE developer COPY CURRENT GRANTS;
```

Comment: Still a little clunky as all relevant object types must be scripted, but cleaner than applying per schema / object type, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To me the statement

`GRANT OWNERSHIP ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE my_clone_db TO ROLE developer COPY CURRENT GRANTS;`

executes but returns

`Statement executed successfully. 0 objects affected.`

even though the database has many schemas in it.

Only `GRANT OWNERSHIP ON SCHEMA my_clone_db.schema_name TO ROLE developer COPY CURRENT GRANTS;` seems to work but then I am back to the problem of having to execute multiple statements, one per schema.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @the_rusteiner.
Statement "GRANT OWNERSHIP ON ALL TABLES IN DATABASE db" does'nt work with schema with MANAGEED ACCESS, even if it's run with the database or schema owner, or even with SYSADMIN.

When the schema has managed access, the grant must be passed at the schema level

Answer (score -1):

@the_rusteiner

That is probably because the role you are running the GRANT as is not the owner of the schema. You can either do:

```
USE ROLE <owner_role>;
```

and try again or execute the GRANT OWNERSHIP as SECURITYADMIN role.